# where do the pointer points to now after the call is done returning the address of the destroyed variable?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* JustATest()
{
    int x;
    x = 5 + 10;
    return &x;
}
void main()
{
    int * ptr = JustATest(); //return address
    cout << *ptr << endl; //the output is 15
}
```

the variable `x` should be destroyed (de-allocated) when the function finish executing then where do the pointer `ptr` point to exactly in memory ?
is the variable x is allocated in the main stackframe pointed to by ptr but its different than the destroyed variable or its the same variable the same memory cell ?

Answer (score 0):

The pointer becomes a *stray* or *dangling* pointer, and dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

If your program have UB (Undefined Behavior) it is ill-formed and invalid.

Comment: The term "dangling pointer" is also used.